# Indexing with NA returns all NAs

Tags: r, na

I've done some digging, but can't seem to find anything that specifically touches on why the output returns:
Code: `c(0:5)[NA]`
Output:
`NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please add the full code, data, and expected output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for how to make the question better.

Answer (score 0):

`NA` is of type logical.

```
class(NA)
[1] "logical"
```

Logicals have a special property in R called as vector recycling. If you subset a vector with a smaller subset it basically recycles the same value.

Example -

```
c(0:5)[c(TRUE, FALSE)] #returns
#[1] 0 2 4

#similarly

c(0:5)[c(FALSE, TRUE)] #returns
#[1] 1 3 5
```

The same is happening here the logical `NA` value is recycled for the entire length (`0:5` here) and you get `NA` of the same length.

```
c(0:5)[NA]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

It would be give a different output for other `NA`'s.

```
c(0:5)[NA_integer_]
#[1] NA

c(0:5)[NA_real_]
#[1] NA
```